# Преобразование двоичного числа в десятичное из массива на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, системы-счисления

Например есть массив двоичного числа, как его переобразовать в целое десятичное?

const binary = [0, 0, 0, 1];

Comment: А насколько большим может быть массив?

Comment: Какое ожидается значение в вашем примере?

Comment: `let number = binary.reduce((res, digit) => res * 2 + digit);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно конвертировать двоичные числа в десятичные:

```js
const binary = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];

function binaryToDecimal(arr) {
  tmp = "";
  for (let item of arr) {
    tmp += item
  }
  return parseInt(tmp, 2);
}

console.log(`Result: ${binaryToDecimal(binary)}`);
```

Или так:

```js
const binary = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];

console.log(`Result: ${parseInt(binary.join(''), 2)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё вот так :p

```js
const binary = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
let result = 0

for (let i = binary.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  let current = binary[i]

  result += current * 2 ** (binary.length - i - 1)
}

console.log(result)
```